# Is this the way I should deploy a asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, deployment, service

I have a solution containing

- asp.net project
- class library
- WCF service class library
- WCF service application

I've added a project refference from the asp.net project to the class library project and to the service class library project.
I've published the asp.net application, loaded it to the webserver root. all ok.

Now for the service, I've created a new folder on the root called WCF, and placed the aplication in there.

Is this The way I should deploy the sollution? Are this the steps when you have more than a simple asp.net application?

PS: How do I change that WCF folder to make it an application trough a control panel because I get this:http://surveillancecamera.somee.com/WCF. The reason why I get this is described here:

Comment: What exactly is described and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would treat the WCF service as a separate entity altogether. Deploy the WCF service and verify it works, then deploy the ASP.Net application.

WCF services have a different set of configuration rules that don't always pair nicely in the same "application root" as your ASP.Net web application. In addition, you may want to use the same WCF service in different applications, and it may not be accessible if it is tightly coupled to this ASP.Net application.